# Setting static IP adress to Android device

Tags: android, adb, static-ip-address

Is there any way to set a static IP address to Android device if the device is connected to a network via ethernet cable using ethernet to USB adapter?

I tried connecting to device via ADB and then changing IP address using $ ifconfig eth0 x.x.x.x command, but I got ifconfig:ioctl 8916: Permission denied as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no way to set it on common devices. You need rooted device, which allows you to run `ifconfig eth0`, thats the only way (valid up to Android 13). By default `eth0` will obtain IP using DHCP, if there is no DHCP available - it just won't work. In "your" network you may assign some particular IP for particular MAC (also ensure that MAC address of ethernet isn't [randomized like for Wi-Fi starting Android 10](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-mac-randomization?hl=en), but it shouldn't be on Linux level)